# replace single character with no method in java

Tags: java, string, methods, replace

If given a string such as "doodle" how could I replace the "e" with the following questions.

Which character do you want to replace?
What do you want to replace it with?
Which e do you want to replace?

The user would input 1 for the final answer and the program would return "doodl_"
with _ being the letter they replaced it with.

The stipulation is that you can only use the methods length(), charAt() , substring, and equals

> if(command1.equalsIgnoreCase("replace single"))
>           {

```
        System.out.println("Enter the character to replace");
        String replace1=keyboard.nextLine().substring(0,1);
        char replace2=replace1.charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Enter the new character");
        String replace3= keyboard.nextLine().substring(0,1);
        char replace4= replace3.charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Which "+replace2+" would you like to replace?");
        int position=keyboard.nextInt();
        int i=0;

        for(i=0;i<input.length();i++)
        {   
            char ichar=input.charAt(i); 


            if(ichar==replace2)
            {
                if(position==i)

                {
                input=input.substring(0,i)+replace4+input.substring(i+1);   
                }
```

>

This is the current code which can only replace a letter given that the index of the letter is also the location of the nth letter to replace.

Answer (score 1):

you can subtract 1 from position every time you see the char and as soon as your position is 0 you found your position:

```
for(i=0;i<input.length();i++)
{   
    char ichar=input.charAt(i); 
    if(ichar==replace2)
    {
        position--;
        if(position == 0)
        {
            input=input.substring(0,i)+replace4+input.substring(i+1);   
        }
    }
}
```